# How to get the properties values those that are defined in the shell (bash) script file using Scala 2.11 code?

Tags: eclipse, bash, scala, shell

How to get the properties values those that are defined in the shell (bash) script file using Scala 2.11 code?

[image]

Also, how do I fetch the (bash) exported values of the **server_env.sh** file? I tried getting it using `sys.env()` however it returns null.

[image]

Comment: I have to get the values from env.sh file as admin team keeps updating it, hence I cannot create a new properties file with all the values.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.util.Properties` has helpers.

```
scala> util.Properties.envOrNone("JAVA_HOME")
res0: Option[String] = Some(/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0)
```

[Similar code in test.](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/test/junit/scala/util/PropertiesTest.scala#L37)